# Can I reference single foreign key on multiple columns in a table? If yes, how to configure it in Entity Framework core

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[image: Single foreign key referencing multiple column in a single table]

How can I generate above table like structure using Entity Framework core?

I am using code first approach to generate my tables from domain models which are as follows

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int FirstContact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int SecondContact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ThirdContact { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

In the company table, I want foreign key on columns 'FirstContact', 'SecondContact', 'ThirdContact' which can refer to Contacts table.

I have also tried Fluent API but no success in same also.

Whenever I am running the add-migration command, I am getting this error:

There are multiple properties with the [ForeignKey] attribute pointing to navigation 'Company.Contact'. To define a composite foreign key using data annotations, use the [ForeignKey] attribute on the navigation.

I would appreciate any help regarding the same.

Thanks.

Comment: you should share at least the starting point of what you are trying to achieve. Provide your current implementation of the 2 classes and how you are trying to achieve your goal, this will help others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple Navigation Properties, you need multiple Foreign Keys.  EG

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact FirstContact { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact SecondContact { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact ThirdContact { get; set; }
}
```

And let EF Core create shadow properties for your FKs or with Foreign Key properties:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int FirstCotactId {get; set;}
    public virtual Contact FirstContact { get; set; }

    public int SecondCotactId {get; set;}
    public virtual Contact SecondContact { get; set; }

    public int SecondCotactId {get; set;}
    public virtual Contact ThirdContact { get; set; }
}
```